# Product Listing Grid View

Tags: magento-enterprise

Is there a way for me to display the grid view of the products in 1 category page only and the rest are in list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by layout update. This will be the best way to do this.

For this I assume, the category that you need to show in list has an id 11. In that case create `local.xml` file like this.

File: `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <CATEGORY_11>
        <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>grid</mode></action>
        </reference>
    </CATEGORY_11>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>list</mode></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
            <action method="setData"><data>_current_grid_mode</data><mode>list</mode></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

This will make category with id 11 in grid view and rest of categories in grid view.

What you need to do here is, just replace `11` with your category id. You can get id of a category from admin side. Go to `Catalog  >  Manage Categories`. Select category that you need to show in grid. You can see its id in top section.

Hope that helps

Comment: hey that works! but when I try to have other page layout (eg: with left sidebar), it doesn't have a sidebar

Comment: I didn't get your point.

Comment: If this answer helped you to resolve the problem in question, feel free to accept this as answer. If you have further doubts, ask it as another question

Comment: I try to change the layout of the category into 2 columns which I have main content and left or right sidebar. but sidebar doesn't appear

Comment: you need to set page layout for that category. Use this for that `<reference name="root"> <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action></reference>`

Answer (score 0):

yes sure,you can do this...

```
rewrite the block Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar



protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
       if (Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()==yourmatchcatid && Mage::registry('current_category') ) { 


              $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Gird')); available modes to grid only.

    }
}
```

**Or**

copy

**app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php**
to

**app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php**
add this code
to

```
if (Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()==youmatchmatcCatId && Mage::registry('current_category') ) { 


          $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid')); 

}
```

Just `before  $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml');` at `_construct` function

**Note**:`This code is remove list of view option from  that particular category category...`

Comment: cannot see block after app/code

Comment: hey check that...